# search multiple strings in a single line with multiple spaces in between

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I want to search for the whole line below from my /etc/pam.d/su file to use it in a script:

```
    auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

there might be multiple spaces in between, and it might be commented out also, with multiple #'s

This is what I'm using :

```
     grep "^#*auth +required +pam_wheel\.so +use_uid$"
```

, but it doesn't yield anything

I'm certainly doing something wrong, but what am I doing wrong? Sorry, have always been bad with regular expressions

Comment: I edited my answer a little... do you need to match the `#` sign or not? I removed it in my answer. At least you have a working example now. Can you give some feedback whether it is working?

Comment: I am using this now: `grep -E "^#*auth\ +required\ +pam_wheel\.so\ +use_uid$" /etc/pam.d/su` but it doesn't help

Comment: exact entry that i have in `/etc/pam.d/su` is: `#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[egrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep) is the way to go, but the question said "multiple" spaces.  That can be done like this

```
egrep "^([[:space:]]*#)*[[:space:]]*auth[[:space:]]+required[[:space:]]+pam_wheel\.so[[:space:]]+use_uid[[:space:]]*$"
```

A backslashed space "\ " is not listed in the special escapes in [regex(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex)  Instead, the POSIX character class can be used.  You could also use *blank* (a GNU extension) rather than *space* to make this only space/tab.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `grep -E` (extended regexp)

```
grep -E "^\ +auth\ +required\ +pam_wheel\.so +use_uid$"
```

this works:

```
echo "   auth required  pam_wheel.so   use_uid" | grep -E "^\ +auth\ +required\ +pam_wheel\.so +use_uid$"
```

gives

```
   auth required  pam_wheel.so   use_uid
```

Comment: No it doesn't work.

`# echo "#auth    required   pam_wheel.so use_uid" | grep -E "^#*auth\ +required\ +pam_wheel\.so +use_uid$"` gave the output 
`#auth    required   pam_wheel.so use_uid` but on the file when i do
`# grep -E "^#*auth\ +required\ +pam_wheel\.so +use_uid$" /etc/pam.d/su` nothing

Comment: can you please copy-paste the exact line in /etc/pam.d/su that you are looking for? try reducing the command to something that works, and then add more characters

Comment: does the line you are looking for really include the `#` character by the way? in my `/etc/pam.d/su` there is none...

Comment: The exact line from the file: `#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid`

multiple spaces between `auth`  `required` `pam_wheel.so`. Only one space between `pam_wheel.so` and `use_uid`

And yes the line is commented out

Comment: maybe there is a space a the end or something like that; try this: `grep -E "^#*auth\ +required\ +pam_wheel\.so +use_uid\ *$"` . You should really try for yourself some variations; try removing the dollar sign to start with; remove characters from your expression until it works and then start adding them again!

Answer (score 0):

Well this finally works for me:

```
    [root@server4 ~]# egrep "^#*auth.*required.*pam_wheel\.so.*use_uid" /etc/pam.d/su
    #auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

I think the issue is in how we are mentioning the spaces.

Comment: I believe @Thomas figured out the issue just perfect